# How to compare (anonymous) function in jest tests?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

I am having the following React component connected to a redux store.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import logo from './logo.svg'
import './App.css'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getWeather } from './actions/WeatherActions'
import WeatherComponent from './components/weatherComponent/WeatherComponent'
import { get } from 'lodash'

export class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.dispatch(getWeather())
  }

  render () {
    return (
        <div className="App">
          <div className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
          </div>
          <WeatherComponent
              weather={{
                location: get(this.props.weatherReducer.weather, 'name'),
                temp: get(this.props.weatherReducer.weather, 'main.temp')
              }}
          />
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect((store) => {
  return {
    weatherReducer: store.weatherReducer,
  }
})(App)
```

This component is dispatching the *getWeather* action using the *componentDidMount* callback. 
The *getWeather* action is returning an anonymous method upon resolving the axios promise.

```
import { GET_WEATHER_DONE, GET_WEATHER_ERROR } from './ActionTypes'
import axios from 'axios'

export function getWeather () {
  let endpoint = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=2a345681ddcde393253af927097f5747'

  return function (dispatch) {
    return axios.get(endpoint)
    .then((response) => {
      return dispatch({
        type: GET_WEATHER_DONE,
        payload: response.data
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return dispatch({
        type: GET_WEATHER_ERROR,
        payload: error.response.data,
        statuscode: error.response.status
      })
    })
  }
}
```

No I am trying to write a unit test verifying the *getWeather* action is being dispatched upon mounting. This tests looks as follows and passes.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import * as actions from './actions/WeatherActions'

describe('app container', () => {
  const store = configureMockStore([thunk])({
    weatherReducer: {
      weather: {}
    }
  })

  const dispatchSpy = jest.fn()
  store.dispatch = dispatchSpy

  it('dispatches getWeather() action upon rendering', () => {
    ReactDOM.render(<App store={store} />, document.createElement('div'))

    expect(dispatchSpy.mock.calls[0][0].toString()).toEqual(actions.getWeather().toString())
  })

})
```

Because of the action returning an anonymous method, I need to call the *toString* method upon my mock to compare the actions.

I recreated this test using snapshot testing.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

describe('app container', () => {
  const store = configureMockStore([thunk])({
    weatherReducer: {
      weather: {}
    }
  })

  const dispatchSpy = jest.fn()
  store.dispatch = dispatchSpy

  it('dispatches correct actions upon rendering', () => {
    ReactDOM.render(<App store={store} />, document.createElement('div'))

    let tree = dispatchSpy.mock.calls.toString()
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  })


})
```

Again I need to call the *toString* method, resulting in the following snapshot.

```
// Jest Snapshot v1, 

exports[`app container dispatches correct actions upon rendering 1`] = `
"function (dispatch) {
    return _axios2.default.get(endpoint).
    then(response => {
      return dispatch({
        type: _ActionTypes.GET_WEATHER_DONE,
        payload: response.data });

    }).
    catch(error => {
      return dispatch({
        type: _ActionTypes.GET_WEATHER_ERROR,
        payload: error.response.data,
        statuscode: error.response.status });

    });
  }"
`;
```

Now when running coverage, using the *yarn test -- --coverage*, my test is failing because of istanbul adding text to my action. The output looks as follows:

```
 FAIL  src/App.snapshot.test.js
  ● app container › dispatches correct actions upon rendering

    expect(value).toMatchSnapshot()

    Received value does not match stored snapshot 1.

    - Snapshot
    + Received

    -"function (dispatch) {
    -    return _axios2.default.get(endpoint).
    -    then(response => {
    -      return dispatch({
    -        type: _ActionTypes.GET_WEATHER_DONE,
    -        payload: response.data });
    +"function (dispatch) {/* istanbul ignore next */cov_2rypo7bhf.f[1]++;cov_2rypo7bhf.s[2]++;
    +    return (/* istanbul ignore next */_axios2.default.get(endpoint).
    +      then(response => {/* istanbul ignore next */cov_2rypo7bhf.f[2]++;cov_2rypo7bhf.s[3]++;
    +        return dispatch({
    +          type: /* istanbul ignore next */_ActionTypes.GET_WEATHER_DONE,
    +          payload: response.data });

    -    }).
    -    catch(error => {
    -      return dispatch({
    -        type: _ActionTypes.GET_WEATHER_ERROR,
    -        payload: error.response.data,
    -        statuscode: error.response.status });
    +      }).
    +      catch(error => {/* istanbul ignore next */cov_2rypo7bhf.f[3]++;cov_2rypo7bhf.s[4]++;
    +        return dispatch({
    +          type: /* istanbul ignore next */_ActionTypes.GET_WEATHER_ERROR,
    +          payload: error.response.data,
    +          statuscode: error.response.status });

    -    });
    +      }));
       }"

      at Object.it (src/App.snapshot.test.js:21:18)
      at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
```

The main problem I am facing is the fact that I need to call the *toString* method for comparison. What is the correct method for comparing (anonymous) functions in jest testing?

Full source can be found at https://github.com/wvanvlaenderen/react-redux-weathercomponent

Comment: Don't rely on a `toString` cast in your test. Write code in a way that can easily hook your test code into it.

Comment: I see you calling `dispatch` in `componentDidMount` but how is `getWeather` using `dispatch`. Perhaps it is too early to be doing snapshot testing. You need to check that `dispatch` is called with the right actions instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able test calls on dispatch by mocking the getWeather action in my test, and verifying the type of the return value on individual calls.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import * as actions from './actions/WeatherActions'
import { spy } from 'sinon'

describe('app container', () => {
  const store = configureMockStore([thunk])({
    weatherReducer: {
      weather: {}
    }
  })

  const dispatchSpy = spy(store, 'dispatch')

  actions.getWeather = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {type: 'fetching weather'}
  })

  it('dispatches getWeather() action upon rendering', () => {
    ReactDOM.render(<App store={store} />, document.createElement('div'))

    expect(dispatchSpy.firstCall.returnValue.type).toEqual('fetching weather')
  })

})
```

Snapshot testing was achieved by rendering the call tree on the dispatch spy.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import { spy } from 'sinon'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import * as actions from './actions/WeatherActions'

describe('app container', () => {
  const store = configureMockStore([thunk])({
    weatherReducer: {
      weather: {}
    }
  })

  const dispatchSpy = spy(store, 'dispatch')

  actions.getWeather = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {type: 'fetching weather'}
  })

  it('dispatches correct actions upon rendering', () => {
    ReactDOM.render(<App store={store} />, document.createElement('div'))

    expect(dispatchSpy.getCalls()).toMatchSnapshot();
  })

})
```

Answer (score 2):

When testing a redux thunk using Jest, i've used `expect.any(Function)`. All assertion libs have something like this.

ex)

action

```
const toggleFilter = (toggle, isShown) => {
  return dispatch => {
    toggle === 'TOGGLE ONE'
      ? dispatch(toggleSwitchOne(isShown))
      : dispatch(toggleSwitchTwo(isShown));
  };
};
```

Test file:

```
beforeEach(() => {
store = mockStore({ showFruit: false, showVeg: false });
      dispatch = jest.fn();
      getState = () => store;
})

it('will dispatch action to toggle switch', () => {
  let res = toggleFilter(type, isShown)(dispatch, getState);
  expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(Function));
});
```